# UI Router query parameters and multiple states

Tags: search, angular-ui-router, query-string

I've been trying to get my head around query parameters with UI Router and think I have finally figured out why I'm having such a hard time with it. I'm building a small search app that has 2 states:

```
$stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/',

.state('search', {
        url: '/search',
        },
```

The home state has its own template (view) and so does the search state. They share the same controller. Basically all home state does is provide a search box to enter your search query or choose from autocomplete.

Once you have submitted your search query it goes to the search state via

```
$state.go('search');
```

I've tried many ways to get the user's search term(s) in the url on the search page using UI Router's query parameter syntax in the `url: '/search?q'` combined with $stateParams in the controller set as

```
vm.searchTerms = $stateParams.q || '';
```

I had switched it to `$state.params.q` but that didn't fix it.

I have successfully been able to get the query parameters in the url, however, when I do, it breaks search functionality. The autocomplete and query parameters work and display, but search function stops.

However, I think I finally understand why its not working the way I'd like it to. I believe it has to do with the fact that I'm using 2 states and not one parent state with a nested child state and that the templates are not nested - so $scope doesn't inherit. I'm getting close to this working... it transitions from the home state to the search state displaying query parameters in the search state's url... its simply that search breaks, but autocomplete and query parameters are working.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the user enter search terms from the home state and then have results display in the search state along with query parameters in the url. Is there anything I need to do with **home** state or **search** state that I'm not doing?

OR

Is there anything in my search() in my controller that could be the problem

```
//search()
    vm.search = function() {
      //$state.go('search', {q: vm.searchTerms});
      $state.go('search');
      console.log(vm.searchTerms);
      console.log('success - search');
      vm.currentPage = 1;
      vm.results.documents = [];
      vm.isSearching = true;
      return coreService.search(vm.searchTerms, vm.currentPage)
        .then(function(es_return) {
          console.log('success - return');
          var totalItems = es_return.hits.total;
          var totalTime = es_return.took;
          var numPages = Math.ceil(es_return.hits.total / vm.itemsPerPage);
          vm.results.pagination = [];
          for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            console.log('success - for');
            vm.results.totalItems = totalItems;
            vm.results.queryTime = totalTime;
            vm.results.pagination = coreService.formatResults(es_return.hits.hits);
            vm.results.documents = vm.results.pagination.slice(vm.currentPage, vm.itemsPerPage);
            console.log('success - documents');
          }
              vm.noResults = true;
            }),
          function(error){
            console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
            vm.isSearching = false;
          },
          vm.captureQuery();
          console.log('success - captureQuery');
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a parameter to your URL in two ways, use colon:

```
'url': '/search/:query'
```

or curly braces:

```
'url': '/search/{query}'
```

Then you can use the `go` method of `$state` with parameter to transition:

```
$state.go('search', {'query', 'foobar'});
```

You can access the parameter's value from your controller by using the `params` member of your `$state` object:

```
console.log($state.params.query);
```

or directly from the `$stateParams` object:

```
console.log($stateParams.query);
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters